# Run cURL commands from Windows console

Tags: windows, command-line, console, curl

Is there a way to install `cURL` in windows in order to run `cURL` commands from the **command prompt**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was [cross-posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2710748/995714)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Download cURL for Windows from [**here**](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) (and be sure to select it from *Win32 - Generic* way down on the page).

[image]

Then place it in a directory inside your PATH environment variable (ie: `C:\Windows\System32`) or run it with its full path preceding the executable name.

If you place it in a directory that's inside your PATH, make sure to close and then reopen command prompt to make the command available.

Comment: You don't need to reopen the console if you put it in a directory on the path, you only need to do that if you *change* the PATH variable.

Comment: One hard reboot later because I couldn't kill the task - um, you might wanna be careful with this.

Comment: Related; can you also install libraries for `https`?

Answer (score 101):

If you install [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/downloads) you get Curl automatically too. There are some advantages:

- Git takes care of the `PATH` setup during installation automatically.
- You get the [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), a really powerful shell, in my opinion much better than the native Windows console.
- You get many other useful Linux tools like tail, cat, grep, gzip, pdftotext, less, sort, tar, vim and even Perl.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know the git bash did the other stuff too :D Thanks a ton!

Comment: worked like a charm!

Comment: This is probably the best all around solution since git is useful for many of the things that curl does but source wise.

Comment: If you have Git, this is a great solution

Comment: Newer versions of git-for-windows do not come with curl in the path, you have to run `/mingw64/bin/curl`.

Answer (score 3):

After installing OpenSSL Light, restart Windows, open Command Prompt, then do a test command like:

```
curl http://www.google.com
```

If you get HTML tags back, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

How to setup cURL:

- Download and unzip 64-bit cURL with SSL.
- Copy the `curl.exe` file into your Windows `PATH` folder. By default, this is `C:\Windows\System32`.
- Download and install the Visual Studio 2010 C++ Runtime Redistributable 64 bit [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13523).
- Download the latest bundle of Certficate Authority Public Keys from mozilla.org [here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).
- Rename this file from `cacert.pem` to `curl-ca-bundle.crt`.
- Move this file into your Windows `PATH` folder.

How to test it:

- Run `cmd.exe` to open your command prompt.
- For both commands, you should see a couple pages of the HTML source code. If you see this, cURL is up and running!

Answer (score 3):

For folks that don't literally need the `curl` executable, but rather just need to e.g. see or save the results of a GET request, can use `powershell` directly. From a normal command prompt, type:

```
powershell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://example.com')"
```

which, while a bit wordy, is similar to typing

```
curl http://example.com/
```

in a more Unix-ish environment.

More information about `net.webclient` is available here: [WebClient Methods (System.Net)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I actually used the `DownloadFile` method: `powershell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadFile('http://.../somefile', 'file.txt')"`. You also just taught me how to use the PowerShell without opening its prompt. Thank you matty!

Answer (score 3):

Tar and Curl are available on Windows beginning in Insider Build 17063, as part of the Windows toolchain: curl and bsdtar.

**Tar**: A command line tool that allows a user to extract files and create archives. Outside of PowerShell or the installation of third party software, there was no way to extract a file from cmd.exe. The implementation uses libarchive.

[image]

**Curl**: Command line tool that allows for transferring of files to and from servers.

[image]

Note: PowerShell does already offer similar functionality (it has curl and it’s own file extraction utilities).

More info:
[Tar and Curl Come to Windows!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/12/19/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

You can install this "cURL for Windows":
cURL for Windows is an MSI installer for cURL, the popular command-line web transfer tool.
http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/

Answer (score 0):

No need to restart windows but restarting CMD is necessary.

1. Install cURL from [curl.haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se).
2. Set Path environment variable according to location of curl.exe in your machine, something like *C:\Users\You\cURL*
3. [Download](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) the certificate file from mozilla.org as linked in one of
   the answers above, and move it to system32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer provided by [fuxia](https://superuser.com/users/51026/fuxia) to run some bash scripts I had written in Linux on the Windows platform. It works very nicely.

A word of caution though with `cURL`. I had an issue where I could not use Console interaction when authenticating as described here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724407/curl-command-in-git-bash

If your `cURL` command requires authentication and you do not want to have the password visible in the command line or stored in your script, you will have to use another solution, like using a password file:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password