# curl windows command line

Tags: windows, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run cURL commands from Windows console](https://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console)

I saw [this questions](https://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console)

I downloaded the CURL and placed it under C. Still I can't run it from CMD (with or without full path). as well, curl seems to be Unix command (sh)

Comment: So... what exactly did you do again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run cURL commands from Windows console](http://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console) (Like you noticed yourself, and without anything more specifics to act on, this is just a duplicate if you'd ask me. Note that, just like Stack Overflow, we're a Q&A site in which duplicates are not very useful.)

Comment: @Arjan Not a duplicate. She mentions that link in her question. She couldn't get anything to run there.

Comment: I disagree, @barlop. I know she mentioned it, but that's not enough to not make it a duplicate, in my opinion. We're not a help forum, are we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the link you mention, found the zip, extracted it, looked for a windows version, it looks like a cygwin thing. Perhaps unnecessary to use that link, since cygwin has curl built into it.

Download cygwin.  see at cygwin.com  an install option links here
http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe
run that.

And when you get this screen  I suggest you click View until it says full(the view button is near the top of the image), then you'll see curl there like this, as you see in the image, they are in alphabetical order.  look down the package column for curl, it's around the 9th line down it's there, see.

When you get the row with curl, you can click where it says skip, so it will be set to install it instead of skipping it.

I suggest maximizing the cygwin setup screen in windows 'cos it makes for less scrolling through the packages.

here is a picture.

you can install cygwin and you'll have curl running.

cygwin is an application that lets you run *nix like commands, from within windows.

[image]

Comment: Cygwin may include cURL, but that link points to native versions as well.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  Well, she didn't notice, and neither did I. But you're right, Scrolling far down the page, under Win32 - Generic.  I see the EXE is there.  I previously tried the Zip at the top, but that wasn't it. Maybe she tried the same wrong thing.

Comment: After running it, will I be able to run curl from command line?

Comment: @Odelya, yes, both the Cygwin version, and [the native Win32 - Generic](http://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console/134687#134687) version, are command line tools.

Comment: Thanks guys actually it was my problem that I didn't see the version for windows...

Answer (score 2):

For reference: yes, if you run Windows then download the windows 32bit or 64 bit binaries:
http://curl.haxx.se/download.html (and not the linux / aix / solaris / etc... versions).

So you do NOT NEED cygwin etc...

Also, I noticed that after installing on Windows I was still missing some dll's it needed so I downloaded these also from Google references and placed them in the same directory as curl.