# No response from CURL at Windows Command Prompt

Tags: curl

I've tried following [Run cURL commands from Windows console](https://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console) but typing in any curl command returns nothing.

See below - I just get back the command prompt.

```
c:\curl>curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

c:\curl>curl google.com

c:\curl>
```

Any clues as to why this may be the case?

Comment: Does `curl -L google.com` work?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to extract the `ca-bundle.crt` file alongside `curl.exe`. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure it didn't already save the file.  If not, try `curl http://www.google.com`.