# How to use,run cURL tool with Android Studio on windows environment?

Tags: windows, command-line, curl, android-studio

What is better way to use cURL tool with Android Studio 1.1.x on Windows? because there is no proper information in official site for client tools on windows environment.

I tried to download from official website, but the downloads are available for windows 2000/XP. And unlike Linux cURL tool, it has got both free and paid version for Windows.

Comment: Next time please do a little research on previously existing questions.

Comment: @slhck, Yes, I understand what you said. Please see my comments. or I will change the English text in my questions.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "what is the better way"? Between which alternatives are you choosing from? What are your criteria? I see you wanted to share some information here, but the best way to share that information is to **improve the existing information** in the linked duplicate, not by posting a new question. You can do this by proposing an edit to the answers, or commenting. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: My intention in not find the  syntax or correct command to execute on windows. My intention is better way to that which I have explained in my updated answer in point#4

Comment: If there is indeed a dodgy website, and you want people to be aware of it, then the best thing is to propose an edit to the existing answer here: http://superuser.com/a/134687/48078 — but I don't see where this dodgy website is?

Comment: @slhck, I acknowledge your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1)I have used my windows Git Hub environment (Git shell) downloaded from https://windows.github.com/
  I want to use cURL  POST data to online forms from both windows and Linux desktops.
- 2)alternatively download from official site [http://curl.haxx.se/download.html](http://cURL%20download)
  [image]
- 3)best way to use cURL tool is, running/executing it on Linux environment.
  cURL is a tool for transferring data using various protocols using URL syntax.
  It can be used in windows command line, it was a project on Linux environment.
  One of the useful and powerful features of cURL too is to GET and POST data to online forms.
- 4) And also please notice the comments of @Toby Allen ==> "Unfortunately the most prominent mirror link for windows does take you to a slightly dodgy website 
  that tries to make you pay / download a dodgy downloader"

[image]

Comment: Your question is marked as duplicate - then why answer it yourself?

Comment: @Prasanna My purpose is knowledge share.  because for windows platform there are no correct information on the official website for free client tool.  hence I used  existing github client tools. Other posts do not mention this properly and makes us to waste time to find the correct download site. 
I hope you understand. Can you remove the down vote.
And also can you notice my third point.

Comment: @Prasanna The question was marked as a duplicate after it was posted. The answer was posted together with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the direct links for the current versions

http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.33.0-win64-nossl.ziphttp://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.33.0-win64-nossl.zip

with ssl

http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.33.0-win64-ssl-sspi.zip

Unfortunately the msi link for windows does take you to a slightly dodgy website that tries to make you pay / download a dodgy downloader.

There links will go out of date, so buyer beware.

Comment: yes you rightly said, it took me to  dodgy website without proper correct information for windows environment.

Comment: My up-vote is for  your valuable information"....dodgy website.....": and "......the links go out  of date...."

Comment: Which dodgy website are you talking about, specifically? When I go to http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and click the Win64/Generic links, they look fine to me.

Comment: follow the msi link and you'll see.

Comment: @slhck  did you get the chance to  windows download page ? plz go through it.

Comment: @SreeRama I did. Like Toby mentioned, the MSI link points to a third party website. That's why one should download the ZIP files. See the answer here: http://superuser.com/a/134687/48078

Comment: @slhck, Thank you for the information. I did not try it, It is not required an android developer using android studio on windows environment. 
I feel, the information for linux env is very clear an concise in the official website, I feel it is not the same for windows environment.